# codeigniter: Validation form without redirect

Tags: codeigniter, validation, redirect

Codeigniter form validation is nice but it is very troubled because it redirect to another url to validate the form. Because sometimes we have the segment in the URL. Being redirect will lose the segment. And in other case user type directly to the validation URL. The example in my case mywebsite.com/class/login_validation.
So how to validation without a redirect or prevent user to type directly to the validation URL.

My view

```
  <?php
        echo validation_errors();
        echo form_open('login_validation');
        echo form_label('Username');
        echo form_input('username',$this->input->post('username'));
        echo form_label('Passowrd');
        echo form_password('password',$this->input->post('password'));
        echo form_submit('submit','Login');
        echo form_close();
        ?>
```

My controller

```
function login() {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('page/login');
    }

    function login_validation() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'required|xss_clean|callback_check_user');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $newdata = array('username' => $this->input->post('usertname'),
                'logged_in' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            redirect('dashboard');
        } else {

            $this->load->view('page/login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to use ajax, seems like a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699201/php-codeigniter-ajax-form-validation

Answer (score 0):

```
$newdata = array('username' => $this->input->post('usertname')
```

please re-check this line `username` instead of `usertname`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to prevent direct entry of the URL is to test the return of `$this->input->method();` == 'post' If true then it isn't a typed in URL.

If you need data to persist across a redirect, use session user data.